# Как извлечь число, обрамлённое префиксом и суффиксом?

Tags: python, строки

Есть константные строковые префикс и суффикс. Приходит динамическая строка вида "положительное целое число, обрамлённое префиксом и суффиксом". Надо достать это число в переменную типа `int`.

Можно ли сделать это проще/лучше?

```
prefix = '['
suffix = ']'

x = prefix + str(42) + suffix

print(int(x.removeprefix(prefix).removesuffix(suffix)))
```

Например, 1 проходом удалить префикс и суффикс. Или, в предположении что префикс и суффикс односимвольные, сразу преобразовывать в `int`, игнорируя символы префикса и суффикса, без манипуляций со строками.

Comment: длины префикса и суффикса - константные?

Comment: @MaxU достаточно решения для односимвольных, можно и для произвольных константных

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Универсальный вариант с использованием RegEx - удаляем из строки все "не цифры":

```
import re

res = int(re.sub(r"\D", "", x))
```

Вариант для заранее известных префикса и суффикса любой длины:

```
res = int(x[len(prefix):-len(suffix)])
```

Вариант для любых односимвольных префикса и суффикса:

```
res = int(x[1:-1])
```

Comment: спасибо, с регексами можно более сложно проверить произвольный нечисловой префикс и суффикс типа `\D+(\d+)\D+`, чтобы логика была понятна из кода + валидация, хотя она не требуется здесь

Answer (score 2):

Вариант для односимвольных префикса и суффикса:

```
print(int(x[1:-1]))
```

Comment: да, вот тоже додумался :)